# How to display Video thumbnail in ImageView?

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I wanted to display my video thumbnail right after taking a video.

This is my current code in the onActivityResult method

```
if (requestCode == 101)
{
  Bitmap bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail("/storage/emulated/0/myvideo.mp4", MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
  viewImage.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);
}
```

But it doesn't display anything on the image view.

Any workaround for this?

*UPDATE: FIXED

I've changed the code to:

```
if (requestCode == 101)
{
       Bitmap bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(f.getAbsolutePath().toString(), MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
       viewImage.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);
}
```

The thumbnail is now showing and I have a bigger size, which is acceptable for viewing. Thanks to Sassa.

Comment: Debug debug debug and debug! It's one of the best friend of developer.

Comment: http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/10/get-thumbnails-in-mediastoreimagesthumb.html

Comment: 1) Check `bmThumbnail` object value before assigning it 2) Giving fixed path of storage directory is a bad practice.

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar His question is different! He wants to display thumbnail of the video right after recording it.

Comment: may be recorded viedo is saved in sdcard and we can get viedo thumbnail from sdcard

Comment: @PareshMayani I've changed the code to:


'Bitmap bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(f.getAbsolutePath().toString(), MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);'

It does return a thumbnail but it is small.

Comment: Update your question with latest code!

Comment: For a different size, try also Thumbnails.MINI_KIND instead of Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND.

Answer (score 1):

I just retrieved the absolute path of the file using f.GetAbsolutePath:

```
if (requestCode == 101)
{
       Bitmap bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(f.getAbsolutePath().toString(), MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
       viewImage.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail will not work with all android OS hence you have to load ffmpeg library in your application to create thumbnail if you want to provide support for all android OS devices.

Thanks,

Devang